# DISTINCT or GROUP BY with subqueries

Tags: group-by, subquery, distinct

Hello I have this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.runcd, 
(SELECT SUM(b.CALVAL) FROM GRS b 
WHERE b.PCode=11000 
AND a.id = b.id 
AND a.runcd=b.runcd) AS qval
FROM GRS a
WHERE a.crt = k04
```

Is this the same one like :

```
SELECT a.id, a.runcd,
(SELECT SUM(b.CALVAL) FROM GRS b 
WHERE b.PCode=11000 
AND a.id = b.id 
AND a.runcd=b.runcd) AS qval
FROM GRS a
WHERE a.crt = k04
GROUP BY id,runcd
```

So far this returns the same result but I dunno if this is the right alternative or not.  Thank You!

Comment: Which SQL? e.g. MySQL, SQL Server etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular query they will always behave exactly the same, regardless of DB vendor (at least I cannot think of any issues with this query using mysql, sql server, postgres or oracle).

Answer (score 2):

> `GROUP BY` lets you use aggregate functions, like `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`,
>   `SUM`, `COUNT` etc while `DISTINCT` just removes duplicates.

See [SQL SERVER – Difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY – Distinct vs Group By.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/)
In your case it will give you same result even you are using subqueries because you are retrieving only `SUM(b.CALVAL)`.